# jQuery load error on refresh ?

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

Here is my code :

```
$('li a').click(function() {
    var link1=$(this).attr('href');
    $('section:#main').load(link1);
    if (link1!=window.location) {
        window.history.pushState({path:link1},'',link1);
    }
});
```

The url on the browser is changing but if the user clicks refresh on the browser it will give the url page only, not the complete one.

Comment: What's the error? Are you expecting the page to remember which tab content was being displayed after a refresh?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [AJAXed tabs with history support](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/ajax-history.html)

Comment: Refresh is supposed to start fresh, as if you're loading the page for the first time. If you want to remember things, you need to use cookies or local storage.

Answer (score 1):

I use a very simple jquery plugin for this.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Works fine and remembers the page loaded by the hash tags, ex: www.site.com/#yourajaxpagetag

Comment: You should also explain that using hashtags can be a way to preserve dynamic information on the client side (and for passing along in history and even to other clients).